# setting number of integers for unlimited argumments

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, for

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing here but I need to be able to get an unlimited number of integers to be provided as arguments

so far I have

```
for sum  in $@; do
        sum=$(($1 + $2 + $3))
done
echo $sum
```

output is
`5`

and my understanding is that it's taking the positional parameters here but How would I get it to do as many as I would be able to put in?

but when i try and add more numbers
`1 2 3 4`

nothing happens, it just says at
`5`

I need to be able to allow for it to loop through an unlimited amount of integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for sum in $@` what's happening is that the variable `$sum` is being set to each value in turn.

You can see this with a simple test

```
for lp in $@
do
  echo $lp
done
```

If you run this with "10 20 30 40" as parameters then you'll see it output each value in turn.

So what you need is a loop with a temporary variable and a sum of the values

```
sum=0
for lp in $@
do
  sum=$(( sum + lp ))
done
echo $sum
```